# How can I use software to check the accuracy of my equations and which software?

Tags: polynomials, math-software

I have been asked to check some engineering calculations even though that is not my area of expertise. Given the complexity of the problem I would like to use a software package to do the verification.

What I have been asked to do is to verify that the two sides of the equation are equivalent. For example I have about a dozen like this (some are far more complex):

$$(RT/(v-Td-c)+(a/Tv^2)-(b/v^4))((v-Td-c)(Tv^2v^4))=((RT^2v^2v^4)+a(v-Td-c)v^4-b(v-td-c)Tv^2)$$

Rather tedious work that I have not done in many years and I am in NO manner a math wizard.

**How do I ask a software package to verify whether two equations are equal and which open source software package should I use for problems of this type?** Also I no longer remember the terminology. Is it factoring? Is it optimization? Is it simplification? Without knowing what this process is called I am handicapped.

Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place to ask. Anyhow, you can use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) for a simple calculation like this (Just evaluate $\text{LHS} - \text{RHS}$ and verify it's zero). If you want more full fledged software, you can use Mathematica (not free) or SageMath (free).

Comment: That's clever.  I wish I had thought of that!  I'll have to give that a try.   I can't justify Mathematica or Maple because I am asked to do calculations very rarely and they are usually quite simple.  I haven't figured out how to use Sage yet. It looks like it will take at least a week to begin to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, if a symbolic math package
can't do it,
is to compute the two sides
numerically for a large number
of randomly chosen values
of each parameter
and see how close they are.

They should be within roundoff error.

This can't prove correctness,
but it would probably show
if the expressions are not equal.

Comment: That sounds like the easiest thing to do! Thanks for the idea.